# Cordova.exec memory leak

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm building a cordova iOS app.

Everytime I call cordova.exec to display a native page, the memory increases significantly.

**Questions:**

1) Is cordova.exec having memory leaks?

2) Anyways to clear this leak?

[image]
https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push/issues/158